# Set view as delegate to viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, delegates

I'm having problem passing data and executing functions in the viewcontroller from the view. I want to access label outlets in the viewcontroller from the view (yeah I know it might be bad structure of my app).

Got delegations working on UIPopovers but how can I set the delegate of the view to viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a subclass of UIView. Let's name it SubClassUIView;
In another view, you want to use the data, from SubClassUIView.
So, your SubClassUIView should be done like this:

SubClassUIView.h

```
@interface SubClassUIView:UIView

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel* someLabelYouWantToUse;

@end.
```

SubClassUIView.m

```
@implementation SubClassUIView

@synthesize someLabelYouWantToUse;

@end.
```

And to access `someLabelYouWantToUse`

```
SubClassUIView* scView = [SubClassUIView alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%@", scView.someLabelYouWantToUse.text);
```

Comment: Didn't get this to work in my case. I think the problem is that my ViewController is already instantiated when the view is showing and with this approach this is done again.

Comment: So, what's the problem? Can you access that label? Is that label initialized?

Comment: Solved the problem with a workaround, but the label was from storyboard with outlet to the viewcontroller so I guess that makes it initialized? Thx for taking time btw